# Como converter "WebClient" para "async/await"?

Tags: c#

Eu tenho código que verifica se tem a internet ou não.

```
public static bool InternetIsConnected()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            using (client.OpenRead("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Como converter o código para `async/await` ?

**Update:**

Tentativa 1: (Comentário do @Virgilio Novic)

```
public async bool InternetIsConnected()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204");
            using (await client.OpenReadAsync(uri))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Código acima dá erro: "Não é possível aguardar void".

**Usando a classe "Ping":** (Funcional)

```
private async Task<bool> InternetIsConnected()
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    try
    {
        await ping.SendPingAsync("google.com", 3000, new byte[32], new PingOptions(64, true));
        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: relacionado: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms144211(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Já tentei fazer, dá erro, fala que não é possível aguardar void.

Comment: `public async Task<bool> InternetIsConnected()` é assim que é o método

Comment: Outra Leitura: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051674/how-to-wait-for-webclient-openreadasync-to-complete

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, atualizei post. Veja o que acha a classe `Ping`. Ou melhor usar `WebClient` ?

Comment: o que eu geralmente faço, é executar em ou outro Thread, e não será nescessário usar o await.

Comment: @isaque pode me dar um exemplo de código ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda `void nome_da_void(){webclient.OpenRead(xxx);/*isso não 'trava seu código'*/} void NOME_OUTRA_VOID(){Thread th = new Thread(nome_da_void);th.Start();}`

Comment: @isaque Mais como vou obter o retorno de true ou false ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda você pode criar um bool, e botar um try e catch(como você fez no código da sua pergunta); se o catch for chamado, essa bool será false.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar o método `OpenReadTaskAsync`, este sim tem suporte ao async/await, o `OpenReadAsync` já existia antes do async/await e dispara um evento quando a operação completa, acredito que por isso tiveram que dar este outro nome ao método para poder dar suporte ao async/await

Outro detalhe é que o retorno de um método async deve sempre ser um `Task`

```
public async Task<bool> InternetIsConnected()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204");
            using (await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(uri))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```